# SAS comparing frequencies of two data sets

Tags: sas, compare, proc

I have two data sets. Their subject is the same group, but different "samples" are drawn by different researchers. Hence,

- I cannot identify matches (i.e. Peter Smith in both samples),
- variables are named differently though they mean the same,
- variables are in different places of the data sets

Now I would like to compare the two data sets to see how similar they are as a whole. I thought about comparing frequency outputs for variables of which I know they have the same meaning.

So far my solution is rather cumbersome in my eyes, because I would have to do all the steps for each combination of variables.

1. Is there a more elegant / efficient solution out there?
2. I would also like to compare mean, median, percentiles for numeric variables.

Thank you very much in advance!

Gerit

Here is my current solution for an example. I named the observations all differently as I cannot, in my original file, tell from the ID variable which observation is which.

```
data have1;                                                   
    input Name $ road means goal ;                           
    datalines;                                                 
adam 1 3 0                                                   
bob 1 1 1                                                      
clint 2 2 0                                                     
dean 3 1 1                                                     
eric 2 1 0 
flint 1 2 1                                                  
gerald 3 1 1                                                 
;                                                            
run;                                                         
data have2;                                                  
    input Name $ street finish other purpose ;               
    datalines;                                               
harry  2 1 0 3                                               
idefix 1 0 0 2                                               
john   3 1 1 2                                               
kelvin 1 0 2 2                                               
liam   2 1 2 1                                               
max    3 1 2 1                                               
nero   2 0 1 3                                               
ovid   3 0 2 3                                               
;                                                            
run;                                                         

proc freq data=have1;                                        
     tables road / out= fhave1road                           
            (rename=(percent=pct1 count=count1));              
quit;                                                        
proc freq data=have2;                                        
     tables street / out= fhave2street                       
            (rename=(street = road percent=pct2 count=count2));
quit;                                                        

data comb;                                                   
     merge fhave1road fhave2street;                          
     by road;                                                
diffpct = pct1 - pct2;                                       
diffct = count1 - count2;                                    
run;                                                         

proc print data = comb;                                      
     var road count1 count2 diffct pct1 pct2 diffpct;        
quit;                                                        

proc means data=have1;
     var road;
     output out=mhave1road ;
quit;
proc sort data=mhave1road;
     by _STAT_;
quit;
proc means data=have2;
     var street;
     output out=mhave2street ;
quit;
proc sort data=mhave2street;
     by _STAT_;
quit;
data mcomb  (keep=_STAT_ road street diff) ; 
     merge mhave1road mhave2street;     
     by _STAT_; 
diff = road-street; 
run;
proc print data = mcomb; 
quit;
```

Comment: Do not merge unrelated datasets! Fortunate for you they have the same number of observations and your statistics make sense, but the dataset you create is crap.

Answer (score 0):

You will get quite some information from

```
title 'have1';
proc means data=have1 min p25 mean median p75 max;
run;
title 'have2';
proc means data=have2 min p25 mean median p75 max;
run;
```

or a graphical equivalent with box plots:

```
title 'have1';
proc transpose data=have1 out=trans1;
    by Name;
    var road means goal;
run;
title 'have2';
proc transpose data=have2 out=trans2;
    by Name;
    var street finish other purpose;
run;
title 'both';
data both;
    set trans1 (in=in1) trans2 (in=in2);
    if in1 then source = 1;
    if in2 then source = 2; 
run;
proc sgpanel data=both;
    panelby source;
    vbox col1 / category= _name_;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The graph looks cool. Is it possible to have the results for two equivalent variables (e.g. street and road) next to each other? It would make a comparison easier. Also, I would like to compare the means etc. of two equivalent variables "automatically". I am far from wanting to merge the data sets. I just would like to compare the deskriptive statistics and to copy and paste into Excel is not so pretty.

Comment: Of course that is possible, Gerit. Basically, you need `category=source` and `panelby = meaning`, in which `meaning` is a variable you fill in based on  the value of `_name_`. I do no have the time to test it today.

Comment: With the graphs I am only missing the step how to get the different meaning side by side and not interrupted by "other" in this case. `data both;
     set both;
     if _name_ in ('goal' 'finish') then meaning = 'goal';
  else if _name_ in ('street' 'road') then meaning = 'road';
  else if _name_ in ('means' 'purpose') then meaning = 'means';
  else meaning = _name_;
run;
proc sgpanel data=both;
    panelby meaning  _name_;
    vbox col1 / category= source;
run;` And how can the deskripitve statistics in numbers be compared?